# How to copy an entire single email from outlook?

Tags: outlook, copy

Our website allows visitors to use their own email client to send in sales questions to our sales staff.  For various reasons, we do not want to switch to a contact form.  In the past, these emails come into myself, and I just forward them on to various sales reps here in our office.

My end goal is to figure out a way get the email into a custom database.  Either by copying the email and pasting the contents onto a webpage that then parses and pulls out the sender, subject and body.  Or possible forwarding the email to an app that runs on our exchange server which does this.

I'm thinking the first option is more in my line of expertise, my problem is I can't for the life of me figure out an easy way to copy the entire contents (headers which contain the senders email address etc) of an email from Outlook so I can paste it into a web form for parsing.  I was hoping somebody could point me to an Outlook addon that can do this.

Best Regards,
Ryan

Comment: Can we have some more information about what language you would like a solution in. Also what is your email server software you may already have the database ready to access instead of pulling from outlook.

Comment: loxp: The email server is exchange, which is in our office.  The language would be php and the database is mySQL.

Comment: Just to clarify, the language for the web page that I was going to use is php.  I am not familiar with writing standalone code that would run on the server itself, like C++.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create an email account account that will be used by some sort of custom application. Your application will periodically connect to the server, download the email and then do whatever processing it is on the downloaded.

Outlook need not be involved at all.

Comment: Outlook is a point of failure.  Not a feature in this design.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I fear it's a bit over my head to create a custom app that runs on the server scanning exchange for the emails.